# How to print a object(stdClass)

Tags: php, object

I have the following `var_dump($result)`:

```
 object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["Res"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

and I dont know how to print the "Res". I tired the following: `echo $result["Res"]` and get:

`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in [...] on line 30`

How to print the content of ["Res"]?

Comment: [The PHP manual ob Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` an object.

So you can do

```
echo $result->Res;
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be as simple as:

```
echo $result->Res;
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated already. You can access this very simple object like so:

```
$result->Res;
```

However, if you had various other elements/objects within, then you'd access each one as follows:

```
$result->{elementname}->fieldname;
```

Just in case you want to go a bit further with it :)

Answer (score 1):

stdClass  is an object , you can't user the echo function with an objector table ...
you have to use a method to view Res:

```
echo $result->Res;
```

or if it's inside a class better use

```
return $result->Res;
```